# wp_mail() sending only last file from the $attachments array

Tags: attachment, wp-mail

I'm using wp_mail() function to send an email with multiple attachments. But only the last element of the array got sent.

```
$attachments = array(
    /home/tpoghrfd/site/vcfact/1/8965784_a.pdf,
    /home/tpoghrfd/site/vcfact/1/8965784_b.pdf,
    /home/tpoghrfd/site/vcfact/1/8965784_c.pdf
);
wp_mail($mymail,$subject, $message,$headers,$attachments);
```

In my mailbox i receive only the last attachment : 8965784_c.pdf

Any suggestions how to fix it?